# how can i install older version of openssl on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, package, version

I downloaded OpenSSL version 1.0.1
and I tried to install that with the below commands :

```bash
$ ./config --prefix=/old-openssl-version-1.0.0g --openssldir=/old-openssl-version-1.0.1
$ make
$ make test
```

but when I enter make test I just receive this error :

> POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 69.
> make: *** [Makefile:595: install_docs] Error 255

This is /usr/bin/pod2man:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
use Pod::Man ();
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);

use strict;

# Clean up $0 for error reporting.
$0 =~ s%.*/%%;

# Insert -- into @ARGV before any single dash argument to hide it from
# Getopt::Long; we want to interpret it as meaning stdin.
my $stdin;
@ARGV = map { $_ eq '-' && !$stdin++ ? ('--', $_) : $_ } @ARGV;
```

I have error on line 69, `my $stdin;`

Can anybody help me to fix this?
If you have a better idea for installing OpenSSL version 1.0.1 it will help, too.

Comment: rooting for this

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev

Comment: "Package libssl1.0-dev is not available" that was what i got when i used the command